# Yii2 Session, Flash messages

Tags: session, yii2

I have a problem with setting flash messages.
So, i have an action which in some cases should redirect with flash. It looks like this:

```
if(!$this->_isSameOrg($reports)){
    \Yii::$app->session->setFlash('consol_v_error',\Yii::t('app/consol', 'some_text'));
    $this->redirect(\Yii::$app->request->getReferrer());
    return;
}
```

After redirect in view i have this

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <?php if(Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('consol_v_error')): ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('consol_v_error') ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

The problem is i don't see any message here. In Debug panel i see SESSION var populated with good flash, but it doesn't display with this if-statement.
Maybe i need to configure session component or something?...

Comment: This might have to do with the redirect, try rendering a test view instead of `$this->redirect(\Yii::$app->request->getReferrer());` and displaying the flash message there.

Comment: do you use Advance Template ?

Answer (score 45):

To set flash,try like

```
  \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'Your Text Here..');
   return $this->redirect('Your Action');
```

And to display it..

```
   <?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('error'); ?>
```

Comment: That's because the flash returned is in an array. You may have got the following error: PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException

Array to string conversion

Answer (score 30):

you can try like this

```
<?php
foreach (Yii::$app->session->getAllFlashes() as $key => $message) {
echo '<div class="alert alert-' . $key . '">' . $message . '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Very good solution to use a global flash section - in the layout for example- to render any flash message. +1

Comment: It's not a good solution, because it retrives ALL the session messages of the application. If you want to implement in a single part of the site the good way to do it is with this  <?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('error'); ?>

Answer (score 14):

Simply do:

1. Add two strings to: `/views/layout/main.php`

   - in block `use`:

   ```
   use frontend\widgets\Alert;
   ```

   - before `<?= $content ?>`:

   ```
   <?= Alert::widget() ?>
   ```
2. Now all messages automatically will be on screen. Lets try it! Add in any controller's method:

```php
Yii::$app->session->setFlash('warning', 'bla bla bla bla 1');

Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'bla bla 2');

Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'bla bla 3');
```

Comment: I prefer this over the other suggestions. In my case I needed to add this widget to my project since I based my install off of the Basic template.

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/common/widgets/Alert.php

Answer (score 9):

Instead of this:

```
$this->redirect(\Yii::$app->request->getReferrer());

return;
```

try this:

```
return $this->redirect(\Yii::$app->request->getReferrer());
```

It's working fine for me.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this is working? (Why should we return the value?). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

in yii2 flash can be set like this

```
Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Thank you ');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:
 overwrite standart Session class:

```
namespace app\components;

use Yii;

class Session extends \yii\web\Session {

    public function getAllFlashesNormalized() {
        $flashes = [];
        foreach (Yii::$app->session->getAllFlashes() as $key => $flash) {
            if (is_array($flash))
                foreach ($flash AS $message)
                    $flashes[] = ['key' => $key, 'message' => $message];
            else
                $flashes[] = ['key' => $key, 'message' => $flash];
        }

        return $flashes;
    }
}
```

So you can:

```
Yii::$app->session->addFlash('success', 'Text.');
Yii::$app->session->addFlash('success', 'Another text.');
```

And output this messages:

```
<?php foreach (Yii::$app->session->getAllFlashesNormalized() as $flash) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-<?=$flash['key']?>" role="alert"><?=$flash['message']?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case flash message deleted after redirect, when i use hasFlash before redirect.

```
if (!Yii::$app->getSession()->hasFlash('success')) {
    Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', Yii::t('app', 'your text'));
}
```

So i added this and it helped

```
if (!Yii::$app->getSession()->hasFlash('success')) {
    Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', Yii::t('app', 'your text'));
} else {
    Yii::$app->getSession()->set('__flash', array('success' => -1));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did not work for me.
I'd rather use:

In the controler:

```
$session = new Session;
$session->addFlash("warning","Your text here");
```

In the view :

```
<?php 
$session = new Session;
foreach ($session->getAllFlashesNormalized() as $flash) { 
?>
<div class="alert alert-<?=$flash['key']?>" role="alert">
    <?=$flash['message']?>
</div>
<?php 
} 
?>
```