# Yii2 setFlash not work or lost if redirect

Tags: php, yii2

I want to set flash message, but flash message always missing. the flow of my controller like this:

```
public function actionOne()
{
    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'message text');
    return $this->redirect(['two', 'param1' => 'value1']);
}

public function actionTwo()
{
    return $this->render('view');
}
```

And on the file view.php

```
<?php
$flashes = Yii::$app->session->getAllFlashes();
var_dump($flashes);
?>
```

I always get empty. How I can show flash message after redirect?

Comment: Maybe session is disabled? Try just save something in session and get it from it on another request.

Comment: can you show me the configuration from working session?

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-session#getIsActive()-detail

Comment: @DonnyAkhmadSeptaUtama Do you have `messages` showing in other cases? Let's say at specific action without redirect?

Comment: yes, if not using redirect, the message show up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yii2 - flash not visible after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161850/yii2-flash-not-visible-after-redirect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case when you redirect to another action - You have to pass third parameter `false`. Link to documentation: [setFlash()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-session#setFlash()-detail)

```
Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'message text', false);
```

In other cases, when you want to show the message in the same action you can use it like this:

```
Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'message text'); // default third parameter is set to true.
```